# SQL - find mis matching values in two tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Ok, here is the issue.

I have two tables, `t1` and `t2`. Using two fields from both:

- product
- POSTED_TRAN_AMT (in t1)
- BEG_AUM_AMT (in t2)

I want to find a product for one period (AP=202, FY=2017) whose `POSTED_TRAN_AMT` and `BEG_AUM_AMT` are different.

Currently I'm stuck here:

```
select PRODUCT, sum(POSTED_TRAN_AMT) from t1 
where FISCAL_YEAR = 2017 and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 202 and ACCOUNT = '995050' 
group by product

union all 

select PRODUCT sum(_BEG_AUM_AMT) from t2 
 where FISCAL_YEAR = 2017 and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 202 group by product
```

NOTE: after manual excel search the outstanding product (with value = 0) appears in t2

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: @Jen R - Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write them as sub-queries and join

```
with t1 as (
    select PRODUCT, 
           sum(POSTED_TRAN_AMT) as POSTED_TRAN_AMT
    from t1 
    where FISCAL_YEAR = 2017 
    and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 202 
    and ACCOUNT = '995050' 
    group by product
) , t2 as (
    select PRODUCT,
          sum(BEG_AUM_AMT) as BEG_AUM_AMT
    from t2 
    where FISCAL_YEAR = 2017 
    and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 202 
    group by product
) 
select t1.product, 
       t1.POSTED_TRAN_AMT,
       t2.BEG_AUM_AMT
from t1 
     join t2 on t1.product = t2.product
where  t1.POSTED_TRAN_AMT != t2.BEG_AUM_AMT
```

---

If the difference might be that the PRODUCT is present in `t1` but not `t2` you would need to use an outer join and modify the WHERE clause like this:

```
select t1.product, 
       t1.POSTED_TRAN_AMT,
       t2.BEG_AUM_AMT
from t1 
     left outer join t2 on t1.product = t2.product
where  (  t2.product is null 
          or t1.POSTED_TRAN_AMT != t2.BEG_AUM_AMT
         )
```

If you don't know which table the PRODUCT might be missing from use `full outer join` and check for null values from both tables:

```
select coalesce(t1.product, t2.product) as product, 
       t1.POSTED_TRAN_AMT,
       t2.BEG_AUM_AMT
from t1 
     full outer join t2 on t1.product = t2.product
where  (  t1.product is null 
          or t2.product is null 
          or t1.POSTED_TRAN_AMT != t2.BEG_AUM_AMT
         )
```

---

> "I also tried different query but it multiplies the values even though having join created. Do you know why this multiplication occurs?"

My query compares the **aggregated values**, your version does not. A variant would be:

```
select A.product, 
sum(A.POSTED_TRAN_AMT),
 sum(B.BEG_AUM_AMT) 
 from A 
      join 
     B on A.product = B.product 
       and A.FISCAL_YEAR = B.FISCAL_YEAR 
       and A.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = B.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD  
   where  A.FISCAL_YEAR = 2017 
   and A.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 202 
   and A.ACCOUNT = '995050' 
  group by A.product having  sum(A.POSTED_TRAN_AMT) != sum(B.BEG_AUM_AMT)
```

Comment: I also tried different query but it multiplies the values even though having join created. Do you know why this multiplication occurs?: select A.product, sum(A.POSTED_TRAN_AMT), sum(B.BEG_AUM_AMT) from A, B where A.product = B.product and A.FISCAL_YEAR = 2017 and A.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 202 and A.ACCOUNT = '995050' and B.FISCAL_YEAR = 2017 and B. ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 202 and A.POSTED_TRAN_AMT != B.BEG_AUM_AMT group by A.product

Comment: Full outer join solution suits me mostly :D

Comment: The provided variant with join does not work due to fact that ACCOUNT field is only available in t1 ;)

Comment: That was a mistake I made in my first suggestion too. Building work code is always hard when the original question doesn't include all the necessary details :(

Comment: don't worry, you nailed it 100%

Answer (score 0):

Here is probably an over-complicated and slow way to do it, but it doesn't make the assumption that every `PRODUCT` is in both tables.

It performs a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on the two summaries you've already created to compare them.  The `FULL OUTER JOIN` will ensure that your results include every product that is in *either* of the two tables.

```
WITH t1sum AS
       (SELECT product,
               SUM (posted_tran_amt) total_amount
        FROM   t1
        WHERE  fiscal_year = 2017
        AND    accounting_period = 202
        AND    account = '995050'
        GROUP BY product),
     t2sum AS
       (SELECT product,
               SUM (beg_aum_amt) total_amount
        FROM   t2
        WHERE  fiscal_year = 2017
        AND    accounting_period = 202
        GROUP BY product)
SELECT NVL (t1sum.product, t2sum.product) product,
       t1sum.total_amount,
       t2sum.total_amount
FROM   t1sum FULL OUTER JOIN t2sum ON t1sum.product = t2sum.product
WHERE  (t1sum.total_amount IS NULL
AND     t2sum.total_amount IS NOT NULL)
OR     (t1sum.total_amount IS NOT NULL
AND     t2sum.total_amount IS NULL)
OR     (t1sum.total_amount != t2sum.total_amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your requirement your query should be something like below

```
(
select PRODUCT, sum(POSTED_TRAN_AMT) from t1 
where FISCAL_YEAR = 2017 and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 202 and ACCOUNT = '995050' 
group by product

minus

select PRODUCT, sum(_BEG_AUM_AMT) from t2 
 where FISCAL_YEAR = 2017 and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 202 group by product
)
union
(
select PRODUCT sum(_BEG_AUM_AMT) from t2 
 where FISCAL_YEAR = 2017 and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 202 group by product

minus

select PRODUCT, sum(POSTED_TRAN_AMT) from t1 
where FISCAL_YEAR = 2017 and ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 202 and ACCOUNT = '995050' 
group by product

)
```